# Need to clean up array output in send mail script

Tags: php, arrays, email

I am not a PHP guy so forgive me if this is something basic.

Here are my three checkboxes on the HTML page:

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="box[]" CLASS="box[]" VALUE="Communication Products Catalog">
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="box[]" CLASS="box[]" VALUE="Optics Catalog">
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="box[]" CLASS="box[]" VALUE="Systems Products Catalog">
```

When I hit submit I have a single php script that just grabs the values of all fields, throws them into a variable and then I use the mail function to send it out.

Here is where I pull the values from the form in my php script:

```
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$addr = $_REQUEST['addr'] ;
$city = $_REQUEST['city'] ;
$state = $_REQUEST['state'] ;
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'] ;
$catalogsa = $_REQUEST['box'] ;
$catalogs = print_r( $catalogsa, true );
```

And finally I "compile" the $msg var which makes up the body of the email:

```
$msg = "First Name:\t$firstname\r";
$msg .= "Last Name:\t$lastname\r";
$msg .= "Company:\t$company\r";
$msg .= "Email:\t\t$email\r";
$msg .= "Phone:\t\t$phone\r";
$msg .= "Address:\t$addr\r";
$msg .= "City:\t\t$city\r";
$msg .= "State:\t\t$state\r";
$msg .= "Zip Code:\t$zip\r\r";
$msg .= "Catalogs:\r$catalogs\r";
```

All of this works and the body of the email does only contain the value of the CHECKED boxes.
But this is what it looks like when I get the email.....

```
First Name: ME
Last Name:  MYSELF
Company:    AND I INC
Email:      NONE@NONE.COM
Phone:      111-111-1111
Address:    222 SOME ST
City:       SOME TOWN
State:      NY
Zip Code:   11777

Catalogs:
Array
(
  [0] => Communication Products Catalog
  [1] => Systems Products Catalog
)
```

I'm looking for a way to clean up the $catalogs variable so it would just look like:

```
Communication Products Catalog
Systems Products Catalog
```

Thanks in advance,

Kenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
$catalogs = print_r( $catalogsa, true );
```

Then do

```
$msg .= "Catalogs:\r";

foreach($catalogsa as $catalog)
{
    $msg .= $catalog . "\r";
}
```

Comment: Just did, was waiting for the clock :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you

```
    $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'] ;
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
    $company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
    $addr = $_REQUEST['addr'] ;
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'] ;
    $state = $_REQUEST['state'] ;
    $zip = $_REQUEST['zip'] ;
    $catalogsa = $_REQUEST['box'] ;
    if(sizeof($catalogsa)>0){
     $catalogs = implode(",",$catalogsa);
    }
```

You can user comma(,) or a new line ("<br/>"). Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $msg .= "Catalogs:";

foreach ($catalogsa as $catalog){
   $msg .= $catalog."\r";
}
```

Comment: Could you also include an explanation of why this fixes the problem?  It's better to give insight in addition to answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$msg .= "Catalogs:\r$catalogs\r";` and `$catalogs = print_r($catalogsa, true);` try with this :

```
foreach($catalogsa as $catalog) {
    $msg .= "Catalog:\r$catalog\r";
}
```

So it will out out this:

```
Catalog: Communication Products Catalog
Catalog: Systems Products Catalog
```